# Am I actually proving that 1 is $\sup$ S for this sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

One topic I am struggling a little bit in analysis is figuring out when I am actually proving something vs just stating the answer slightly differently and not actually proving anything.

The sequence is

S = {$x \in \mathbb{R} | x<x^2$} and I need to prove that 1 is $\sup$S

I proceed by contradiction and assume $l$ is an upper bound for S such that $l <1$. If $l<1$, then $l^2<1$, so by the archimedean property, we can define $l<k<1$.

But then $l<k$ and $k^2<1$, so $k \in$ S, but since $l<k$, $l$ cannot be an upper bound of S. This contradiction shows that 1 is $\sup$S

Is this an acceptable way to prove something?

Comment: You've proved that anything below $1$ is not an upper bound, now you have to prove that $l=1$ is an upper bound, then you can conclude that $1$ is the sup since there are no upper bounds smaller then $1$.

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks-is it sufficient to show that 1 is an upper bound to show something like: $1^2 = 1$ and that all $x>1$ could be expressed as $(1+n)$ where n is some arbitrary constant, so 

$(1+n)^2 = $ 

$1^2 + 1*n + 1*n + n^2 = $ 

$1 + 2*n + n^2 > 1 +2*n > 1+n$?

Comment: How does $l < k$ and $k^2 < 1$ show that $k \in S$? For $k$ to be in $S$, you need to show that $k < k^2$. Also $1^2 = 1$ is not necessary to show that $1$ is an upper bound. Upper bounds can be a part of the set. But, the rest does show that $1 + n \notin S$ for $n > 0$, which does show that nothing greater than $1$ is in $S$. That is what shows $1$ is an upper bound.